# 2005 Ford E150 Econoline

Tags: ford, idle, stall, van, econoline

hope someone can help with this.

I have what seems to be a strange problem.  When accelerating to at least 2400 RPM in 1st gear and then completely removing my foot from the gas, the engine RPM drops all the down, eventually stalling.

It doesn't seem to be happening in any other gear and only manifests itself at RPMs higher than 2400.

When idling the RPM is around 500-750 and hunts within about 100 RPM ryhtmically.  That is to say, it's going up and down in a predictable and consistent pattern.

It doesn't seem to be happening when the vehicle is in Park.

It's the 4.6L V8 Petrol version.

Any ideas?

Comment: We need to start with any repair history, codes, scan data (such as fuel trims) and fuel pressure to help guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this an automatic or standard shift vehicle?

Comment: Ah sorry I knew there'd be something I missed.   It's automatic.

Comment: The only problem that I've had with the vehicle is a "minor EVAP leak" - the engine warning light has been on for a while but I've never had this issue before.

Comment: Further testing:  The issue also manifests itself when applying full steering lock and applying the minimum amount of gas.

It seems that this is an issue that is affecting the engine when it is at the very bottom of it's RPM range.  

It sometimes will stay in first gear and the RPM refuses to change, despite applying more pressure to the throttle.  This is only transient and a firm push of the accelerator resolves it.